# Special characters in Razor template not being encoded correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I make some test with ASP.NET Core MVC.
I am trying to display special character like çùé.

But it is displayed as �.

Exemple :

Create new view and put :

```
<div>àçù</div>
```

By default, the `.cshtml` file is encoded in "UTF-16".
The charset in HTTP response header is "UTF-8".
In _layout, the `<head>` contains the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tag.

To resolve the problem, I can convert all .cshtml file to uft-8.

What's the correct way to manage encodage in ASP MVC Core?

Edit :

Visual Studio 2017 RC create .cshtml file in 'utf-8', but the scaffolding create the .cshtml file in 'ISO 8851-1'.

Can I explain to scaffolding I want .cshtml file in 'UTF-8'?

Comment: Please post the piece of code where your trying to display this characters.

Comment: I took the freedom to rephrase title and the content, to make it easier to read/understand.

Comment: The issue is known : https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/144

Comment: But, how did you solve it. I have same issue and couldn't figure out how to solve, or I cannot see the actual solution from the github link you shared. I'm also working with ASP.net core on VS community 2017

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by simply opening the file with problems, confirming it was encoded as ANSI, converted it to UTF-8 and everything run smooth again. I also created a post for this, so both seem duplicated right now. [MVC .net core is not displaying special characters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512883/mvc-net-core-is-not-displaying-special-characters-correctly/45577036#45577036)

Answer (score 1):

What did it for me is copying the view's content into Notepad++, deleting the file, adding it anew, and pasting the saved content.